# Python: puzzling behaviour inside httplib

Tags: python, debugging, httplib

I have added one line ( `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` ) to httplib's HTTPConnection.putheader, so I can see what's going on inside.

`Python26\Lib\httplib.py`, line 489:

```
def putheader(self, header, value):
    """Send a request header line to the server.

    For example: h.putheader('Accept', 'text/html')
    """
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    if self.__state != _CS_REQ_STARTED:
        raise CannotSendHeader()

    str = '%s: %s' % (header, value)
    self._output(str)
```

then ran this from the interpreter

```
import urllib2
urllib2.urlopen('http://www.ioerror.us/ip/headers')
```

... and as expected PDB kicks in:

```
> c:\python26\lib\httplib.py(858)putheader()
-> if self.__state != _CS_REQ_STARTED:
(Pdb)
```

in PDB I have the luxury of evaluating expressions on the fly, so I have tried to enter  `self.__state`:

```
(Pdb) self.__state
*** AttributeError: HTTPConnection instance has no attribute '__state'
```

Alas, there is no `__state` of this instance. However when I enter `step`, the debugger gets past the

```
if self.__state != _CS_REQ_STARTED:
```

line without a problem. Why is this happening? If the `self.__state` doesn't exist python would have to raise an exception as it did when I entered the expression.

*Python version: 2.6.4 on win32*

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Name_mangling_in_Python

`__state` is a private name inside the object, it gets mangled as `_HTTPConnection__state`, so when I want to access it in PDB I have to name it as `self._HTTPConnection__state`. Only the object can refer to it as `__state`.

Answer (score 0):

> If the self.__state doesn't exist python would have to raise an exception as it did when I entered the expression.

In Python, you don't have to declare variables explicitly.
They are "born" when you assign to them.

Some code validators like pylint warn about these situations.
In your case you could have something like `self.__state = None` in `HTTPConnection.__init__()`

but this is not very important.

Comment: Sorry, you don't seem to understand the question. How can httplib get away with referencing a non-existing variable without raising an exception?